# Integrate external app on wordpress page?

Tags: wordpress

I want to create my own web app with js/html/css and integrate it to an existing wordpress page. 
I don't want to use wordpress itself but just create it myself and host it on the same server.

Is it possible to include an outstanding app into a wp site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're creating this page in something like Codepen. If you're just using html, yes, you can just add that page into the current website structure. But why would you want to do that, when you can insert the html into a page inside the Wordpress editor. If you want to add css, you can do that in the html with inline css. Same with js, just add the script into the html.

Comment: So I really need to add a whole page of html with inline css/js?

Comment: Yes-any page is made up of html.

Comment: I also could use an html file with external css/js in the root folder of WordPress, can't I?